# Hyper-V 2016 vs KVM Performance

Tags: hyper-v, kvm-virtualization

We have 2 VM clusters here with identical hardware, all fully patched to latest levels.
We have been testing running some linux workloads on the 2016 cluster and found a big difference in performance.

We were initially alerted to the issue by seeing that the applications running on the 2016 cluster were running slower. We have since done some benchmarks using Geekbench and our suspicions have been confirmed.

To keep a clean use case we did the following:

- Ubuntu 20.04 VM with 4 cores and 10GB ram
- No other VM's running on host
- VM's set to host cpu, not an emulated type
- Confirmed no mitigations enabled for Meltdown/Spectre
- We then ran the Geekbench tool on each VM.

Hyper-V 2016, single core result: 595, multicore result: 1940
KVM, single core result: 679, multicore result: 2352

as you can see there is around a 15% drop between the two.

Is this normal?

Comment: It doesn't seem entirely out of line. Now if you really want your head to explode, run a CPU benchmark on a Windows VM.

Comment: A great suggestion. I am interested in comparing Geekbench results Windows guest vs Linux guest on Hyper-V.